# How can i make a script load faster?

Tags: javascript, html

Im making a digital clock for my webpage. But every time i enter the page, it takes 1 second before the string with the current time appears. Is there any way to change that and make it faster so it is not that notisable for the user? Thank you

My js code:

```
const add_zero = (number) => {
    return number < 10 ? `0${number}` : number;
}

const show_current_time = () => {
    setInterval(() => {
        const today = new Date();
        const month = today.getMonth() + 1;
        const year = today.getFullYear();
        const date = today.getDate();

        const hours = add_zero(today.getHours());
        const minutes = add_zero(today.getMinutes());
    
        const current_date = `${date}/${month}/${year} ${hours}:${minutes} |`;
        
        document.getElementById("show_current_time").innerHTML = current_date;
    }, 1000)
}

window.onload = show_current_time;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It "takes 1 second before the string with the current time appears", because the function `show_current_time` has `setInterval` and the last argument is `1000` (1 second).

The function is doing more than what its name suggests: showing the current time. It's also updating it each second. It starts the first update after the document is loaded.

Remove `setInterval`:

```js
const show_current_time = () => {
  const today = new Date();
  const month = today.getMonth() + 1;
  const year = today.getFullYear();
  const date = today.getDate();

  const hours = add_zero(today.getHours());
  const minutes = add_zero(today.getMinutes());

  const current_date = `${date}/${month}/${year} ${hours}:${minutes} |`;

  document.getElementById("show_current_time").innerHTML = current_date;
}
```

If you add `show_current_time();`, it will call the function sooner.
Calling `setInterval(show_current_time, 1000);` updates it each second.

```js
window.addEventListener(
  'load',
  () => {
    show_current_time();
    setInterval(show_current_time, 1000);
  }
);
```

I avoid using `window.load` because you lose everything you did with it when you change it.

There might be a gap between the beginning of the document being loaded, and the functions being called. But, depending on the script size how, and how it's loaded, probably it's not noticeable.

Answer (score 2):

You can try calling a function that does the work once, and only then do the *setInterval()* for that function.

```
set_current_time()
setInterval(set_current_time, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

use requestAnimation frame, on a recursive loop:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame

Answer (score 0):

```
const show_current_time = () => {
    const today = new Date();
    const month = today.getMonth() + 1;
    const year = today.getFullYear();
    const date = today.getDate();

    const hours = add_zero(today.getHours());
    const minutes = add_zero(today.getMinutes());

    const current_date = `${date}/${month}/${year} ${hours}:${minutes} |`;
    
    document.getElementById("show_current_time").innerHTML = current_date;
}
show_current_time()
setInterval(show_current_time,1000)
```

Comment: "My suggestion:" is inside the JS code. May you move it?